# Adjusting mercurial notify extension to send notification due to a certain string in the commit message?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook, mercurial-extension

I need to send notifications to certain email due to a certain string in the commit message in the mercurial repository.
I have now the notify extension working but it sends notifications at every push. 
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `notify` extension as a reference and roll out your own hook that will examine the commit messages in incoming changesets and send out emails if they contain a certain string. The book [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) has a [great chapter on writing hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html), which should help you get started.

Comment: thx so much :) , is it possible to enable/disable the notify extension through a python script ?

Comment: Writing your own "version" of `notify` that is based on patterns in the commit messages might be a cleaner way to do what you asked about. Extensions are [enabled](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UsingExtensions#Enabling_an_extension) by simply adding an entry for them under `[extensions]` in `mercurial.ini' or 'hgrc'